# I need help reading binary/hex string response from Serial RS485 device

Tags: javascript, binary, serial-port, hex, rs485

I have posted this question previously, but I am posting again to gain more clarification. I received some responses from another user on my previous post that I will include here. Here is the link for the Operation Manual for the serial RS485 device: 
`Operation Manual - https://www.lesker.com/newweb/gauges/pdf/manuals/392usermanual.pdf`

`Link to previous post - shorturl.at/prxHK`

```
*PDF pg. 59: RS485 Serial Communicatoins - Binary Protocol
*PDF pg. 61: Notes when using Binary Protocol
*PDF pg. 62: RS485 Commands Summary*
```

- Every command **sent** will begin with `'!' (hex 0x21)` and **responses from device** will begin with `'*' (hex 0x2A)`
- Response length = length of command sent

`Sending a command to the unit:`

```
Byte 0: '!' (hex 0x21) <-- start character
Byte 1: '1' (hex 0x01) <-- address of unit, this is a constant
Byte 2: '2' (hex 0x02) <-- command byte value, this will change as you change commands
Byte 3: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care UNITS
Byte 4: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care data 1
Byte 5: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care data 2
Byte 6: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care data 3
Byte 7: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care data 4
Byte 8: 183 (hex 0xB7) <-- CRC - Carriage return - Not actually typed by user

For testing, this command is physically sent through a serial terminal as: 
'0x21 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xB7'
```

`RECEIVING a response from the unit:`

```
Byte 0: '*' (hex 0x2A) <-- start character
Byte 1: '1' (hex 0x01) <-- address of unit, this is a constant
Byte 2: '2' (hex 0x02) <-- command byte value, this will change as you change commands
Byte 3: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- UNITS: 0=Torr, 1=Pascals, 2=mBAR
Byte 4: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- floating point byte 1
Byte 5: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- floating point byte 2
Byte 6: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- floating point byte 3
Byte 7: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- floating point byte 4
Byte 8: 148 (hex 0x94) <-- CRC - Carriage return

This response is received in serial terminal as: '2A 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 B7' 
or '0x2A 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xB7'
(not sure if that's how it actually responds, or if my terminal program automatically formats
```

So as you can see, in my previous post I have been provided with code for decoding / encoding commands / responses from the device in the required Hex code format, however I am unsure of exactly what form the device responses are in. For example, I can currently only get a response using something like RealTerm terminal for serial comms, I send a test command pulled from the manual:

```
SENT:
Read IG Pressure - '0x21 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xB7'

//Byte 0 (0x21) is the leading '!' start char, and Byte 8 (0xB7) is the CRC, which is not entered by user

RESPONSE:
Received in the format of - '2A 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 0X94'
//I sent the command while the gauge was disabled, so the floating pressure readout values are all 00 in the response
```

Now in order to start parsing data and assigning variables to bytes, I need to know if the data coming back from device looks like the response above, or if my terminal program is doing some formatting before displaying it to the user. 
Before I can determine what the data coming back actually looks like, I am needing help with writing the code for setting up `serialport`, I am a bit of a noob and I am learning as I go, so I am not sure what readline/delimiter/parser to use, do I need to include some kind of buffer? I tried modifying this code based off of some other guides related to `serialport` but I am not able to get the code to return values when I do `console.log(data)` which should hold the device response.

**Code:**

```
        poll3(state){
            const SerialPort = require('serialport')
            const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline')
            this.port3 = new SerialPort('COM16', {autoOpen: false, baudRate: 9600, dataBits: 8, stopBits: 1})
            this.port3.open (function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    //console.log('Port3: ', err.message)
                    state.err.serial3closed = true
                }
                else {
                    state.err.serial3closed = false
                    console.log('Port3 is open')
                }
            })
            const parser = this.port3.pipe(new Readline({delimiter: '\r'})) //should I do this differently?
            parser.on('data', function(data){
                console.log(data)  // <---- **this is not working, and not returning the response**
                })
```

I have an `action` for triggering this `poll3 mutation` above in my store.js file, the `#01RDS` is one of the ASCII commands I was using previously. That command will be replaced and look like this:

```
OLD:
getSys(context) {
            store.dispatch('write3', '#01RDS')
        }
NEW
getSys(context) {
            store.dispatch('write3', '0x21 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xB7')
        }
```

So in sum, I am needing to read the response from this device, which I currently have ONLY had success with via a terminal program like RealTerm (for some reason I can't even get a response in PuTTy) and to read the response I need to make sure my code for setting up my serial comm's is correct. Currently I know it wrong, but Im too new with this stuff to determine where the issue is. I had help writing the code I have for sending/reading serial data via ASCII Protocol, so Im unable  to fully understand why I did some of the things I did in that code. If anyone can help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I commented on your last question like this. I was looking through your profile just now: You haven't marked any of the questions you have asked as answered. When you have a chance, can you go and update them: For each,either select an answer as the solution to your question, or add your own answer and select that?

Comment: Sorry ControlAldDel, I just went through and did that. Any thoughts on this question here?

Comment: *"I have been provided with code..."* -- That code is probably broken.  IMO you've made your program too complex, and should simplify.  First learn how to use serial communication with ASCII text instead of the binary protocol.  This is also suggested in the instrument manual on Page 67: *"It is recommended that if you are not familiar with the use of the BINARY protocol described in this section, please consider using the ASCII type protocol ... Using the BINARY protocol requires special programming knowledge and capability."*

Comment: @sawdust We were already using ASCII protocol over Serial, I am aware that the conversion to Binary Protocol is more difficult, hence why I am asking questions about it. Binary Protocol offers a wider range of commands, in particular there is a command that reads ALL pressures and outputs them in order, through ASCII protocol we are not able to do that, this is one of the main reasons we are needing to switch to binary protocol.

Comment: @sawdust I am confident that I now have the ability to finish the rest of this task once I establish proper serial communication with this device over binary protocol. I will take your advice and study over the serialport usage / examples to gain a better understanding of the topic. In the meantime, if you have any pointers that may be helpful, I would appreciate it! Thanks